# Updating 11M rows database and my.cnf optimisation

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, sql-update, easyphp

I have to update 11M rows from a database in a PHP script.

After some time, the script freezes or crashes. I have to restart EasyPHP 12, and reload it.

My configuration:

- Windows 7 Pro 64 bits
- Intel Core i7 860 2.8Ghz
- 8G RAM

My my.cnf file :

```
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_concurrency = 8
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id = 1

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Here is the pseudo code that crash.

```
`For i to 100000 { do magic (check content on the web);    UPDATE table;    }`
```

Comment: what has php got to do with it, what's the logic in your php file?

Comment: If you're doing transactions, you may be hitting the limit of the transaction itself. How did you determine the script freezes or crashes?

Comment: Are you able to write a stored procedure to achieve your goal?

Comment: The `check content on the web` part is to be handled with care! A web request can time out, so set sensible timeouts for wget/curl. Also put an `echo` or `print` after each cycle so you know where you are at.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look into php.ini, not my.cnf.

I suppose you are performing some logic on a single record and updating that record, then on to the next one. In this case the update of a single record (or a subset of records) should not take *that* long.

The *freeze or crash* is either because your script hits the memory limit or its execution time limit.

Comment: Maximum execution time is on "no limit mode".
I use now CLI and this is better even if it crash sometime when the script run for example more than 8 hours.

My script is like that (an like said Jelmer) :

SELECT * FROM TABLE limit n,100000
   UPDATE something for each ID

I don't know where this crash (how to know for example what limit is reached) ...

Comment: So, you accepted an answer that didn't solve your problem? Rewrite/Edit the question, put your script in it (at least in pseudo code)... comment at the solution you have accepted, not everywhere else. Don't loose context!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into an execution time error. You could create a shell script an run that via your command line.

for example (pseudo):

```
<?php
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT $x to $y

FOR every result
do some magic, SAVE to record with ID $id
```

If you call this file `my_update.php`, run it by typing `php path/to/my_update.php` and watch the magic. (where `php` is the php executable).

Be smart and log every action! So when the script fails you have a nice trail and don't have to start all over again! That is exactly why I added the LIMIT in the query so it doesn't have to buffer 11M of rows, but just a few. After the first bunch of rows it will simply go to the next LIMIT. Sort of like pagination, but without visual output.

Sources:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: I add pseudo code for my long script on my question post.

Maximum execution time is on "no limit mode". I use now CLI and this is better even if it crash sometime when the script run for example more than 8 hours. My script is like that : SELECT * FROM TABLE limit n,100000 UPDATE something (check content websites) for each ID.

I don't know where this crash (how to know for example what limit is reached). Mysql and Apache log say nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the maximum execution time of script from php.ini file.

Comment: Maximum execution time is on "no limit mode".
I use now CLI and this is better even if it crash sometime when the script run for example more than 8 hours.

My script is like that :

SELECT * FROM TABLE limit n,100000